# Hyperledger Fabric : Failed to send peer responses for transaction 'xxx' to orderer

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-cello

I have deployed the Hyperledger fabric on AWS using cello ansible with dockers. Everything works fine. I was able to do a transaction using composer playground. In a process for vertical scale-up the system, I have created a bigger AWS instance using old AMI. I have correct all the dns, docker and flannel settings. Updated /etc/hosts files on both the VMs. Brought all the docker container up and running. Now when I try to do a transaction, I am getting below error by composer-playground:

```
Error: Error trying invoke business network. Error: Failed to send peer responses for transaction '02be502e532dfe5c153fa2fc5ecbb599a387834e32f4eb5b1806949335cfcd26' to orderer. Response status 'SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE'
```

I have checked all the docker logs(i.e. orderer, peer, kafka, zookeeper) could not able to find exact error.

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I was able to scale up the fabric network with below steps:
1) Stop the AWS instance
2) Change the type of AWS instance
3) Start the AWS instance and bring up all the docker container.

Comment: Hey. I am face Response status 'SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE. Can have any solution for that

Comment: @salmanfaris have you followed the process as I mentioned the comment? If yes then can you please let me know in which order you are bringing up docker services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to scale up the fabric network with the following steps:

1. Stop the AWS instance
2. Change the type of AWS instance
3. Start the AWS instance and bring up all the docker container.

Now bring up the service in this order: ca, zookeeper, kafka, orderer, couchDB, peers, client applications.

Comment: Is the problem that the underlying resource of the server is too low? Do I need to scale the server up?

Answer (score 0):

@Gaurang Singh

whenever a new transaction happened after endorsing happens client will send it to orderer.

**SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE**:

Which means orderer is not able to communicate with other orderers, kafka is not reachable.

Kafka ordering service has numerous connection problems.

Tip1: try to restart orderers one by one it will connect to kafka brokers and work properly

Tip2: use raft instead of kafka

Comment: Sorry. My issue already solved. Thanks for contreibuting @Narendranath Reddy

Comment: atleast give him the bounty then :D